# Can you help me making more mobile responsive navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have tried making responsive navbar using Bootstrap 5, but my `navbar-brand` gives me problems. Letters overflow over other elements and my `toggle-icon` goes to new row and it should be in right corner in the same row as navbar header.
Here is codepen:
https://codepen.io/namename123/pen/VwQzRPL

```css
.logo-iddeea {
  font-family: 'Agency FB', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left,rgb(254, 168,100), rgb(240,104,69));
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.logo-image{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
.portal-open-data{
  font-size:1.3rem;
  margin-top:-5%;
}
.nav-link {
  color: #2c3474;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.blue-color-font {
  color: lightblue;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .logo-slika{
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .logo-iddeea{
    font-size:2.5rem;
  }
  .portal-otvorenih-podataka{
    font-size:0.8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/agency-fb" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark container-fluid bg-dark offset-0">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"> <img src="https://shoutcart.com/uploads/gig/bd6f3a23cd5294a2370b09bc413f3331.png" alt="" class="d-inline-block logo-image"></div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 ps-4 ps-md-1 my-md-auto logo-iddeea">
              AABBA
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 ps-sm-1 ps-4 blue-color-font my-md-auto portal-open-data  ">
              SOME COMPANY <div style="margin-top:-3%;"> TEXT</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse ms-5">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item  ">
          <a class="nav-link blue-color-font">Groups</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown  ">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle blue-color-font" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Passwords</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link blue-color-font">Administrators</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item  ">
          <a class="nav-link blue-color-font">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item  ">
          <a class="nav-link blue-color-font">Documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item  ">
          <a class="nav-link blue-color-font">Activity logs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown card shadow">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle blue-color-font" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Logged Username</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end orange-border">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item blue-color-font">Reports</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item blue-color-font">Settings</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider blue-color-font"></div>
          <a>Logout</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i would consider simplifying the logo altogether, or atleast have a media query that removes some of the elements to the logo when its conditions are met. you have a lot of different elements in your navigation bar, putting them all together in 1 row is difficult to make responsive on smaller screens. you could also make the burgermenu appear at the 992px breakpoint (tablets) instead

Comment: Is it better idea if I use image as a navbar-brand instead of using logo icon and text.  I know it is some type of hard coding, but maybe that would make it more simple? EDIT: I mean using AABBA and SOME COMPANY TEXT together with a company logo as a single image

Comment: yeah, just removing either the image or the text altogether would make the navbar less packed

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a><img src="https://shoutcart.com/uploads/gig/bd6f3a23cd5294a2370b09bc413f3331.png" alt="" class="mx-2 img-responsive logo-image"></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-iddeea" href="#"><h1>AABBA</h1></a>
    <span class="text-info"> SOME COMPANY TEXT</span> 
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Groups</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">User</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Administrators</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Documentation</a>
        </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Activity logs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

use this code and remove all styles which are not required